# Install Python Package within an Existing Python Package

Tags: python, pip, package

I have a question about the entry points part of the setup.py for python packaging and I couldn't see to find on the setupptols site: https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/userguide/entry_point.html?highlight=entry%20points

If I create an add on, called 'fooviewer' and I want to it be installed in a sub-package of a package called 'bartime'

so the import would go like this:

```
import bartime.fooviewer as fv
```

but `bartime` is not installed, would the package just create the `bartime` path or would the setup.py through an error?

I don't want to make `bartime` a requirement if it doesn't exist because fooviewer could work with or without `bartime` if that makes sense, but I want to show it's part of bartime's library package?

Comment: That's a bad idea. You probably want to have a top-level package `bartime_fooviewer` instead. Or... maybe you are looking for something called ["namespace packaging"](https://packaging.python.org/guides/packaging-namespace-packages/), which would mean that the top-level package `bartime` has to stay empty, all import modules have to be in sub-packages of `bartime`, for example: `bartime.fooviewer`, `bartime.core`, `bartime.something`, etc.

Comment: i think `namespace packaging` would work.  I thought of that as well, so many options.

Comment: If you're sure you need namespace packaging, then use only the "native" namespace packages. And make sure to have strictly no code, no python module, no files, no `__init__.py` in any of the `bartime` top-level packages. Only other sub-packages. Otherwise it is not a namespace package and things will break sooner or later.

Comment: ok, I saw that and I have a small example working thank you.